# convert ByteArrayOutputStream to FileInputStream

Tags: java

I have stream saved in `ByteArrayOutputStream`. now I want to to read that in `FileInputStream`. how Can I do that?

it's my outputStream.

```
...
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
```

now how to read that, from `FileInputStream`?

Comment: outputStreams are meant for writing, you can read from them

Comment: close the outputstream, and open the file with the fileinputstream?

Comment: Stream is in my memory - it's ByteArrayOutputStream. 
then I need FileInputStream variable, of that Stream.

Comment: I don't have file. I have ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a `ByteArrayInputStream` with

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
```

and then read from this `InputStream`.

If your interface only accepts a `FileInputStream` then the interface is broken...

If, at all, an interface only works with files it should accept a `File` else it should use an `InputStream`.

Also if you use threads you can use `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` directly between the threads.

Comment: I need only FileInputStream. or I have byte array  (byte [] variable) and I want to read from FileInputStream

Comment: +1 for "If your interface only accepts a `FileInputStream` then the interface is broken"